# Spring MVC SseEmitter - connection aborted Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Springs SseEmitter like in this post:
[Angular 2 spring boot server side events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987560/angular-2-spring-boot-server-side-events). The push events are working but everytime I'm closing or refreshing the tab I've got the exception below.

The strange thing is that the exception is thrown within the *send* method of the emiter which is surrounded by a try catch block. The exception must be catched and logged and rethrown within the method. But how can I prevent it. I don't want to suppress the error log.

```
IOException: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde softwaregesteuert durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen

IOEexception an established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Thanks!

**SseController.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class SSEController {

    public static final List<SseEmitter> emitters = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList<>());

    @RequestMapping(path = "/stream", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public SseEmitter stream() throws IOException {

        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();

        emitters.add(emitter);
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> emitters.remove(emitter));

        return emitter;
    }
}
```

**ServiceClass.java**

```
@Scheduled
public void sendSseEventsToUI(Notification notification) { //your model class
        List<SseEmitter> sseEmitterListToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        SSEController.emitters.forEach((SseEmitter emitter) -> {
            try {
                emitter.send(notification, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                emitter.complete();
                sseEmitterListToRemove.add(emitter);
            }
        });
        SSEController.emitters.removeAll(sseEmitterListToRemove);
    }
```

Exception:

```
> 2017-12-27 13:54:53.206  INFO 4248 --- [pool-4-thread-1]
> o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : An error occurred in
> processing while on a non-container thread. The connection will be
> closed immediately
> 
> java.io.IOException: Eine bestehende Verbindung wurde
> softwaregesteuert durch den Hostcomputer abgebrochen  at
> sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]     at
> sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
> ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
> sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
> ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
> ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
> sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
> ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1267)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(Http11OutputBuffer.java:581)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:272)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1560)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:283)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
> org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
> sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
> [na:1.8.0_121]    at
> sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) [na:1.8.0_121]
>   at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
> [na:1.8.0_121]    at
> org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:119)
> [spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
> [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:41)
> [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227)
> [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:207)
> [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.send(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:200)
> [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:166)
> [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:159)
> [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:126)
> [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:107)
> [spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
> com.example.demo.PushService.sendSseEventsToUI(PushService.java:22)
> [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> ~[na:1.8.0_121]   at
> org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
> [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
> [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> [na:1.8.0_121]    at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
> [na:1.8.0_121]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> [na:1.8.0_121]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
> [na:1.8.0_121]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> [na:1.8.0_121]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> [na:1.8.0_121]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: What is the Spring version you are using? I can not reproduce the issue you have

Comment: I don't realy understand your problem given that we don't know what is the line 22 of PushService.java and the given shouldn't print any stacktrace. Could you please update your question with the actual code and line number info. The issue occurs when the client close the connection.

Comment: I've created an example project. https://git.io/vNff7. Run it - open chrome http://localhost:8080 wait until a guid is printed, close the tab/browser. The next time the send method is called the stacktrace is printed despite I've catched all errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing a log from org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor. You are getting it because the servlet api that doesn't notify when a client connection is closed. That's why it try to write on the socket anyway, more info at [jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13292](http://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13292)

If you don't want to see this log change the log level for this package by adding this property (in your application.properties):

```
logging.level.org.apache.coyote.http11=ERROR
```

Or you can edit your logger configuration file.

Furthermore don't use static final collection for keeping your emitter do something like:

In your service

```
private final Collection<SseEmitter> emitters = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new HashSet<SseEmitter>());

public void register(SseEmitter emitter) {
    emitter.onTimeout(() -> timeout(emitter));
    emitter.onCompletion(() -> complete(emitter));

    emitters.add(emitter);
}

private void complete(SseEmitter emitter) {
    System.out.println("emitter completed");
    emitters.remove(emitter);
}

private void timeout(SseEmitter emitter) {
    System.out.println("emitter timeout");
    emitters.remove(emitter);
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
public void sendSseEventsToUI() { //your model class
    for(SseEmitter emitter : emitters) {
        try {
            emitter.send(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            emitter.complete();
        }
    };
}
```

In your controller:

```
@Autowired
public PushController(PushService service) {
    this.service = service;
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SseEmitter stream() {
    final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(0L);
    service.register(emitter);
    return emitter;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to surpress the log cause there could be some useful informations. Maybe the problem is a missing check in Springs emitter which should check if the connection is aborted before sending. Or the emitter could provide a isConnected method or something like that to check it programatically. From my description: "I don't want to suppress the error log."

Comment: The problem comes from the servlet api that doesn't notify when a client connection is closed. That's why it try to write on the socket anyway. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13292

Comment: Thanks! Please update your answer with the link to the ticket and the information that the servlet spec doesn't provide a notification for a connection lost so that it can't handled properly and I'll accept it!