# Update mat-table data after making change to database

Tags: angular, angular-material2

First, just want to say I'm fairly new to Angular, Material, and http so if you could be specific or include a code snippet with any response I'd appreciate it.

I'm pulling data from a db2 database and able to display it in a mat-table. I can edit the database using a matform and httpclientmodule; however, when I make changes I can't get the table data to refresh without reloading the page.

I tried the paginator trick (where you set the paginator value to the current value to trigger a table update) but I don't think it works when using http.

Does anyone have a good solution for this? Here is some of my code:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, Injectable, OnInit, 
ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatInputModule, 
MatFormField, MatInput, MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {merge} from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import {of as observableOf} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {catchError, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class ContractorsDao {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  // Sends request including which field to sort by and to sort asc or desc
  getContractorRecords(sort: string, order: string, page: number): 
Observable<Contractor[]> {
    const href = 'http://localhost:8080/pzapp-servlet';
    const requestUrl =
      `${href}/controllercontractors?message=getMstx&sort=${sort}&order=${order}`;
    return this.http.post<Contractor[]>(requestUrl, 'getMstx');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-contractors',
  templateUrl: 'contractors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contractors.component.css']
})
export class ContractorsComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

// Initialize items for contractor mat-table

  // Columns displayed on the table
  displayedColumns = [
    'contractor-name',
    'contractor-phone',
    'select-contractor'
  ];

  // Initialize mat-table data source
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Contractor>();

  // Initialize local database
  contractorDatabase: ContractorsDao | null;

  // Initialize mat-table features
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  selection = new SelectionModel<Contractor>(false);

  editContractorForm: FormGroup;

  // Specific record selected
  activeRecord: Contractor;


  contractorsUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/pzapp-servlet/controllercontractors';

  // Triggered when record is selected from table
  viewRecord(row) {
    // Stores selected row for display
    this.activeRecord = row;
    this.editContractorForm = new FormGroup({
      NAME: new FormControl(this.activeRecord.NAME),
      PHON: new FormControl(this.activeRecord.PHON)
    });
  }

  // Takes filter text and filters table
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); 
  // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.editContractorForm = new FormGroup({
    NAME: new FormControl(null),
    PHON: new FormControl(null),
    });
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.contractorDatabase = new ContractorsDao(this.http);
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.contractorDatabase.getContractorRecords(
          this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
      }),

    ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  }
  onSubmit(value: any) {
    this.http.put(this.contractorsUrl, this.editContractorForm.value).subscribe();

  //  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}

// Interface for PZCNTR listing
export interface Contractor {
  PCNAME: string;
  PCPHON: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create new instance of `ContractorsDao` and assign it to `contractorDatabase` variable after successful edit:

```
 onSubmit(value: any) {
    this.http.put(this.contractorsUrl, this.editContractorForm.value).subscribe(response => {
      this.contractorDatabase = new ContractorsDao(this.http);
      // here probably the rest of the code from ngAfterViewInit (so you can probably wrap it into a method)
    });    
  }
```

Comment: ^ this. mat-table listens to changes to the whole data array.. not to changes to the single elements of it.... to update each element singularly you have to use other routes... probably doe to the fact that mat-table was created to display static data more than anything else... that said... inside your cell definitions in your template you can still bind variables to the elements of said array in order to update them... say an <input matInput [(ngModel)]="element.id"> for example

Comment: Mateusz I had actually already tried that but it didn't work for some reason

Comment: Mateusz Witkowski  I did some testing and it does work but sometimes I need to call the onSubmit  method twice. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: @Richard are you sure that correct (changed) data is always passed to the `onSubmit` method?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your requirement correctly, what you want is to auto-reload data once the data changed in the DB. The way I see it, you have following options.

1. Use a timer to call data fetch method periodically. This will be the easiest to implement. See http://beyondscheme.com/2016/angular2-discussion-portal

   ```
   private refreshData(): void {
       //fetch data here
   }

   private subscribeToData(): void {
       this.timerSubscription = Observable.timer(5000).first().subscribe(() => this.refreshData());
   }
   ```
2. Using server-side events to get a notification to the front end and then fetch for data changes. See an example here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41540858/1849366
3. Using web sockets. See https://g00glen00b.be/spring-angular-sockjs/

You'll get plenty more samples for the above methods on the web.

Comment: @downvoter would be nice if you could explain the reason for the downvote as well.