# Angular back end service call without rest call

Tags: angular, angular-services

Is it possible to call back end service from angular 4 without REST specific way ?

I want to implement a GUI but using REST is restricted, so I want other way to call my service.

In short, I want to create a traditional MVC project where Angular is VIEW. rest of the thing will remain as it is like in traditional framework.

Comment: You could use WebSockets

Comment: you can also use server side events. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987560/angular-2-spring-boot-server-side-events

Comment: In these techniques also I will have to implement REST API at server side that I dont want, I want to create a traditional MVC project where Angular is VIEW... rest of the thing will remain as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **WebSockets** to communicate with a Back End for an angular application.

WebSocket is a different protocol from HTTP, it enables interaction between a web client (such as a browser) and a web server with lower overheads. The communications are done over TCP port number 80 or 443 in case of TLS-encrypted connections.

Example of a service: [Real Time Apps with TypeScript: Integrating Web Sockets, Node & Angular](https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Message } from '../model/message';
import { Event } from '../model/event';

import * as socketIo from 'socket.io-client';

const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    private socket;

    public initSocket(): void {
        this.socket = socketIo(SERVER_URL);
    }

    public send(message: Message): void {
        this.socket.emit('message', message);
    }

    public onMessage(): Observable<Message> {
        return new Observable<Message>(observer => {
            this.socket.on('message', (data: Message) => observer.next(data));
        });
    }

    public onEvent(event: Event): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<Event>(observer => {
            this.socket.on(event, () => observer.next());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In these techniques also I will have to implement REST API at server side that I dont want, I want to create a traditional MVC project where Angular is VIEW... rest of the thing will remain as it is.