# Is it possible to create multi page apps in angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am thinking of creating a clone of Food ordering applications like Zomato, and I found out that it uses Angular like routing on certain pages that are at the time of Ordering after selecting a Restaurant.
i.e. the page is not refreshed can be seen from the Reload button on the browser and it seems that the request doesn't go to the server.

While on other sections such as selecting a restaurant the request does seem to get routed by the server.

So my question is that Is it feasible to make a multi-page application in angular?

and if yes then how please provide some links of a demo or something on the Internet, and if no then what should be the architecture of such a Food ordering app?

The architecture I am thinking:

[image: Architecture]

But I am stuck at the problem that how will the server be able to render or request angular to get the data, I know the way angular can request the server to fetch the data using Restful Services but I don't know how the server will be able to pass control to the angular app when user requests for a particular URL that is designed for the angular app such as the URL at the time of ordering.

Comment: What kind of server are you using, if you are using NodeJS then you are already all set!

Comment: How can I use node js , please clarify all set, thanks a ton.

Comment: It is mostly implemented by passing all possible routes , e.g site.com/* to angular - index.html, then angular automatically handles the url, and having a separate route, site.com/api/* which points to the backend and not to the index.js, this is the most common practice...

Comment: if you are interested in this approach I can suggest you a more detailed answer!

Comment: I know that but then how will it be a multi page application when only one page is changing index.html changing into different pages using different components.

Comment: I am interested in any approach please send some link where this approach is elaborated, thanks.

Comment: tushar you have got this wrong angular is used to create SPA ( Single Page Application ), the multiple pages are implemented using the angular router, which basically loads the same index.html each time and reads the window.location ( url ) and loads relevant components to page. P.S. it does not create different pages for each urls.

Comment: I am interested in this approach and want to learn more about this please send some link which elaborates this approach, thanks a lot.

Comment: I want that some Url s are handled by server and some by angular, by means of application server I mean node express or spring boot.

Comment: As I told you you could exclude some paths like site.com/api/* ... I am just finding the resource it's been a while since I have seen it.

Comment: So there are server  handled paths and angular handled paths , but how when a action is performed in a template of server which then wants that angular route is displayed how will that thing executed?

Comment: You can read this https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: Listen Angular is not used to create typical php/form submit websites you must use technology like ajax / sockets to communicate with server , the server must be headless i.e. it should not produce any ui it should just act as a api returning answers to a ajax request, not producing ui! You should handle every aspect of ui in angular only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me - and especially looking through the comments, with various people giving appropriate responses - that you're not exactly aware what SPA (Single Page Application) are. What you're attempting doesn't make a whole lot of sense. While I've seen some hackish solutions that are coming close to what you want, it's an awful mess that is highly unmaintainable.

If it's SSR (Server-Side-Rendering) what you want (Pages are being served from the backend) , the official Documentation of [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) is something you should look into, but that would require you to serve your Application with Node.js. If you want to keep your Java Spring backend, you will have to consider a Server to Server Communication

Comment: I think thats exactly what I was wanting thanks ak.

Comment: The thing that is in my mind is to create a website which has partial angular section and partial standard server routed section. Will that be feasible?

Comment: @tusharsharma That's not something that should be done by your Spring Backend. Your Spring Backend shall only provide the Data for your SPA. Your single page application has to make a Cross Origin Request to your Spring Backend.

Answer (score 0):

If server wants to get some data from frontend without any request from frontend. then you can use server sent events. You can refer to [Angular 2 spring boot server side events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987560/angular-2-spring-boot-server-side-events). This link have an example which shows that how spring boot can send an event to ui and how ui can get that event. After ui receives this event. You can trigger an http call from ui to backend send the data required by backend.

Comment: Thanks let me have a look at it.

Comment: @tusharsharma did you find it useful?

Answer (score -1):

If I'm good understand your question - Angular is SPA (Singe Page App) framework that interacts with the web browser by dynamically rewriting the current web page. So i think you can not create multiple page in Angular.

If you want to use  multiple web pages (i.e. index.html, page1.html) use Thymeleaf which is java template engine and integrates with Spring-Boot applications, for example:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf

If you are using REST API from Spring-Boot and want to send request to the backend server, server will not respond until you add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. The quick example is:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping("/product")
public ResponseEntity<List<YourEntity>> getAllProducts() {
  //use service or repository for get data from db
  return new ResponseEntity(entities, HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

In Angular, you need to subscribe data by subscribe() method, for example:

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

      values: any;

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        this.values = [];
      }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getDataOnStart();
   }

   getDataOnStart() {
      this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/products').subscribe(data => {
           this.values = data;
         });
  }

 }
```

Where localhost:8080 is your Spring-Boot (server) address.

After that when you reload the page `ngOnInit` will send request to the server.

Example app:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

Comment: Thanks Falcon, actuallt my question was a little different, I want to create a web application that uses Angular but only partially and other routes are managed by spring boot template such as thymeleaf and on clicking the thymeleaf template link I want control to be passed to angular for the purpose of implementation of buying cart and reviews and other features

Comment: Ok, so you can use angular as standalone application or implement Microservices architecture for that -  where carts/reviews and others will be one service and other content will be another service. Maybe this framework will help you achive this:
[link](https://www.jhipster.tech/) - Jhipster supports microservices architecture and much more i.e. code generation, database planning