# SSE (Server-side events) in Spring - storing SseEmitters

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I am implementing SSE events in a web application. My use case requires possibility to selectively send events to some or all subscribed clients. I already have a working draft of  implementation both on the server side/ Spring and client side/ Angular - based on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987560/angular-2-spring-boot-server-side-events).

Now, since SSE requires the connection to be maintained, my application becomes stateful and I need to manage that state somehow. The only idea that comes to my mind is storing this in memory as a Map<UserId, SseEmitter> being a field within a singleton service. This would require proper synchronization to ensure thread-safety, but this can be easily achieved by using e.g. ConcurrentHashMap. The SseEmitter class itself seems to be thread-safe.

Typically services are stateless in Spring, but I can't think of any alternatives or reason why the approach described above would fail. Does anyone can suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would say **just try to avoid state as possible!**.

In your sentence `since SSE requires the connection to be maintained, my application becomes stateful`, just because you keep a TCP connection open doesn't mean your application should be stateful.

IMHO you can create data streams as wanted/required and your interested clients can subscribe to them, in that way, you can handle your events like a Queue manager.

I created something similar here https://github.com/htenjo/vqueue with the following architecture:

[image]

Maybe it can help.